# Getting 2 separate JSON array in android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, arrays

I have the following 2 separate JSON Arrays

```
    {
    "Menu": [
        {
            "date": "2014-11-01",
            "day": "Saturday",
            "food_of_the_day": "Stripped beef Spanish Style with rice",
            "extra": "Sweet peas and mixed salad",
            "special": "-",
            "dessert": "fruit cocktail"
        },
        {
            "date": "2014-11-30",
            "day": "Sunday",
            "food_of_the_day": "Pabellon criollo de Venezuela",
            "extra": "salada",
            "special": "-",
            "dessert": "Ice cream"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this other JSON array

```
   {
    "update_time":
                 [
                  {
                   "update_time_row":"2014-11-11 19:00:15"
                  }
                 ]
    }
```

To get an idea of what I mean, here is the webpage: http://syncandroid.comuf.com/loading_data.php

I can already fetch the json array with the title `Menu` and populate it inside my listview in my android app,  but the separate one with the title `update_time` is giving me a headache.
Here follows a snippet of my code:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray("jsonResult");

for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++){   
 JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);  
 // get all value here   
 String dateOfMainCourse=oneObject.getString("date");  
 String dayOfMainCourse=oneObject.getString("day");   
 String mainCourse=oneObject.getString("food_of_the_day");   
 String extraFood=oneObject.getString("extra");   
 // get other values from jsonobject in same way    
}
JSONArray jArray2 = new JSONArray("jsonResult");
 for (int i=0; i < jArray2.length(); i++){   
 JSONObject oneObject2 = jArray2.getJSONObject(i);  
 // get all value here   
 String update_time=oneObject.getString("update_time");  
 Toast.maketext(getBaseContext(),update_time,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

but when I do it the same for the array of `update_time` I get a  `nullpointerExeption`

How can I fetch that single line of JSON array ?

Comment: Please note, what is the Menu block is one single array with the name/index "Menu". The single array has two elements.

Comment: You haven't shown the the code that you are using to access "update_time" so we have now way to propose a solution.

Comment: The link you provided returns two json objects in same page. I mean {json1}  {json2}. Its not possible to parse two different Json objects in android.

Comment: You need to get it separately in order to parse it android.

Comment: ok just updated the snippet code

Comment: It seems you have not understood the JSON format. In your Json content, There is no "jsonResult" array. And "update_time" is not a string

Comment: share the complete json you are tying to parse since your code and json do not match.

Comment: Ok Indra, thank you. Sorry I didn't read your previous reply. I thought it was possible to parse 2 different json object in a string. Ok then i'll parse them separately.

Comment: @RainierGaari Make it a single JSON. Need any help Let me know

Comment: @Indra  THANK YOU VERY VERYYY MUCHHH!.. simple and yet best idea ever. Finally, thanks to you, I've managed to get that JSON object.. Thank you very very much